# Flask: Getting request parameters based on Content-Type header

Tags: python, rest, flask

What is the proper way to deal with the request body depending on the `Content-Type` header of the request?

I need to implement a RESTful service that supports XML, JSON and form encoded request parameters, but I can't seem to find a clean way of extracting the request parameters.

Is this something that I should use a middleware for? Do I need to extend the Request object?

I haven't found any packages that do this, and it seems like a pretty common task for creating RESTful services in flask.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant Accept header, as Content-Type is used for response.  There are three choices here:

1. Build it youself as described in [Handling Accept Headers](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/45/) snippet.
2. Use Flask-RESTful extension (consult [Content Negotiation](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#content-negotiation) part in the docs).
3. Use [Flask-Pushrod](http://flask-pushrod.readthedocs.org/) extension which is specifically built to handle this case.

Comment: No, I actually did mean content type.

The accept header is important for responses, but I want to be able to handle incoming request data whether it be JSON, XML, or form params.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I read your question too hastily the first time, sorry for that. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to your _actual_ question, but would like to hear it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@app.before_request` as illustrated [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/). Once you've done your thing normalizing the request params, you can [save them to `g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.g), something like this:

```
from flask import g
from flask import request
...


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # normalize params based on Content-Type
    g.params = normalized_params
```